# Do the egg colours mean anything?

Tags: yoshis-crafted-world

In past Yoshi games, the different coloured eggs meant something - red ones gave you health, yellow eggs gave you coins, etc.

I don't seem to notice anything like that happening in this game, though. Am I just somehow not noticing the effects? Do coloured eggs have effects in this game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, similar to past Yoshi games, colored eggs do have special effects rewarding ricochets. Yellow eggs give you coins, red eggs give you hearts, and blue eggs will give you 3 new green eggs. [Source](https://toptwitchstreamers.com/yoshis-crafted-world-what-we-know-so-far/)

Comment: I am highly amused at my obliviousness.